# Finite strings from infinite alphabet

Tags: computer-science

Is the set of all strings of finite length $\Sigma^*$ from a infinite alphabet $\Sigma$ uncountable?

The usual procedure in these types of proof is that you

```
list strings of length 1
list strings of length 2
list strings of length 3
.......

.......

.......
and so on
```

But now even the first line has infinite length so the construction can never stop. What is wrong?

Comment: Assuming the Axiom of Choice, the set of finite strings from an infinite alphabet has the same cardinality as the alphabet. But your method does not work, because the first "list" never ends, so you never get to the the list of strings of length 2. To show countability in the countable sense, well-order the alphabet, list words of the same length lexicographically, and then imitate the proof that the positive rationals are countable.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin if the alphabet was finite then my method would work right?

Comment: Yes, it would: in that case each line of your table would be finite.

Comment: hi could someone please help me out with this proof. Iam stuck ? :(. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Arturo: You actually don't need the axiom of choice at all here. If the alphabet is countable then without the axiom of choice you can show that the finite strings form a countable set; if the set was not countable to begin with... well, the result will not be countable.

Comment: @Asaf: Right; my caveat came from thinking about the assertion that "the set of finite strings has the same cardinality as the alphabet" in the infinite case. I agree on the countable case. But the proof I know for the general case uses a lot of cardinal arithmetic, and you've taught me to be careful in asserting it holds without AC. Does the general case of *equal cardinality* hold regardless of AC?

Comment: @Arturo: Indeed to show that the cardinality is *the same* requires and even implies the axiom of choice; however in here we are merely arguing countability vs. uncountability. In this aspect there is a very obvious map from the alphabet into the finite strings which ensures us that if the alphabet was uncountable then the finite strings are uncountable.

Comment: @Asaf: Okay, so my statement is correct, since the clause "Assuming the Axiom of Choice" is modifying "the set of finite strings form an infinite alphabet has the same cardinality as the alphabet." (-:

Comment: @Arturo: Of course, my remark was merely to suggest that the axiom of choice is not required to show countability or uncountability of this set, since deciding whether or not this set is countable can be deduced directly from the cardinality of the alphabet. If you want to calculate the cardinality the axiom of choice will indeed be useful. :-)

Answer (score 5):

If the set of letters is uncountable, so is the set of words. For a finite or countably infinite alphabet, one can imitate your argument closely without getting into difficulties.

List the alphabet as  $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$. Let the *complexity* $c(w)$ of a word $w$ be the largest integer $i$ such that $a_i$ appears in $w$ **plus** the number of letters in $w$.  It is clear that for any $n$ there are only finitely many words $w$ such that $c(w)=n$.

Write down the word(s) of complexity $0$ (there is only one, the empty word). Next down the word(s) of complexity $1$, in lexicographic order. Then write down  the words of complexity $2$, in lexicographic order. And so on.

We conclude that if the set of letters is non-empty and finite or countably infinite, then the set of words is countably infinite.

Answer (score 4):

If your alphabet is countably infinite and ordered then you can

- List all strings of length $m$ using letters up and including the $n$th where $m+n=2$
- List all strings of length $m$ using letters up and including the $n$th where $m+n=3$
- etc.

If you wish, you can start with the empty string.

Each of the sublists is finite (you can use your suggestion within each sublist) and so the overall list is countable.

Answer (score 3):

$\Sigma^*$ is countably infinite. Recall,

\begin{equation}
\Sigma^* = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \Sigma^n
\end{equation}

for every value $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the set $\Sigma^n$ is countable, therefore, $\Sigma^*$ is a countable union of countable sets, thus it is countable.

**Proof:**

We must provide a bijection, a mapping of every element in $\Sigma^*$ to a unique element in $\mathbb{N}$, that is, a function which is one-to-one and onto.

Let $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$ and $f:\Sigma^* \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be our bijection.

Now we start by writing down all the strings in $\Sigma^*$ in increasing order. First all strings of length $0$, then all strings of length $1$, all strings of length $2$, all strings of length $3$, so and and so forth.

\begin{equation}
\Sigma^* = \{\epsilon, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 110, 101, 111, ...\}\\
\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ... \}
\end{equation}

Upon inspection of the above, we clearly have a bijection $f:\Sigma^* \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, that is a function that maps every element of our alphabet to a unique element of the natural numbers. Therefore, $\Sigma^*$ is countably infinite. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

You have succumbed to a common fallacy: one proof does not generalise but that does not mean there is no other proof. The technique you use fails here but can easily be fixed.

Assume your alphabet is countable, i.e. $\Sigma = \{a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots\}$. The idea is that you can (recursively) enumerate the set $\Sigma^n = \{w \in \Sigma^* \mid |w| = n\}$ for any fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and then interleave all these (countably infinitely many) enumerations.

In order to enumerate $\Sigma^n$, consider the following construction (note that $\Sigma^1 = \Sigma$ serves as an anchor) which interleaves the enumerations of $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^{n-1}$, concatenating their elements to the words of $\Sigma^n$:

$\qquad \Sigma^n = \{\ \Sigma_0\Sigma^{n-1}_0,\quad \Sigma_0\Sigma^{n-1}_1, \Sigma_1\Sigma^{n-1}_0,\quad \Sigma_0\Sigma^{n-1}_2, \Sigma_1\Sigma^{n-1}_1, \Sigma_2\Sigma^{n-1}_0,\quad \dots \ \}$

By continuing this scheme, you enumerate whole $\Sigma^n$ (in a computable way).

Now, $\Sigma^*$ can be enumerated in the very same way:

$\qquad \Sigma^* = \{\ \varepsilon, \quad \Sigma^1_0, \quad \Sigma^1_1, \Sigma^2_0, \quad\Sigma^1_2, \Sigma^2_1, \Sigma^3_0,\quad \dots\ \}$

The technique used is often called [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_%28computer_science%29). If you write the whole space as a table, you can see that it closely resembles the [canonical scheme for enumerating the rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDiagonal_argument.svg).

Note that if $\Sigma$ is uncountable $\Sigma^*$ is trivially uncountable, too.